# Error publishing WCF service with net.tcp bindings

Tags: wcf-binding, net.tcp

I'm trying to publish a WCF service on IIS 7.5 net.tcp enabled and I get the following error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the
>   endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [http].

Attached the web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="BLAlgorithmService" behaviorConfiguration="BLAlgorithmService.Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http//localhost:56795/Algorithemservice" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="DuplexBinding"
                  contract="IBLAlgorithmService"  />
        <endpoint address="mextcp" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior  name="BLAlgorithmService.Behavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="10000" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>

        </behavior>
        <behavior name = "MEX">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="10000" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>

      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DuplexBinding"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="64000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="64000000"
                 closeTimeout="02:50:00"
                 openTimeout="02:50:00"
                 receiveTimeout="02:50:00"
                 sendTimeout="02:50:00">
          <readerQuotas
               maxDepth="2147483647"
               maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
               maxArrayLength="2147483647"
               maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
               maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <reliableSession ordered="true"
             inactivityTimeout="10:50:00"
             enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Try pointing the base address to your svc file if you have one. And try visiting the svc file in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your base address should be `net.tcp://localhost:56795/Algorithemservice`

Comment: Thanks for that , I changed the service web.config as advised still I'm getting the same error **Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].** thanks , Rony